# Values in array of structs print out as garbage after Initialization

Tags: c, struct

This is an issue I’ve been rather stumped on for the past day. Below, I am calling a function, `setuprooms()` from my main function, which fills out a 3×3 array of structs that was passed in. When I print out the contents of this array in the `setuprooms` function, the output is clear.

However, when I do this in the main function, I get a bunch of garbage values. Is it a problem with memory allocation or something else entirely? Does the board array need to be dynamically allocated? Kind of stumped.

The struct I’m using:

```c
struct Room
{
    char* name;
    struct Room *north;
    struct Room *south;
    struct Room *east;
    struct Room *west;
};
```

The struct constructor I’m using:

```c
struct Room * rmconstruct(char* name, struct Room *north, struct Room *south, struct Room *east, struct Room *west)
{
    struct Room *newRoom;
    newRoom = (struct Room*) malloc(sizeof(struct Room));

    newRoom->name = name;
    newRoom->north = north;
    newRoom->south = south;
    newRoom->east = east;
    newRoom->west = west;

    return newRoom;
}
```

The `setuprooms()` function, which loops through 9 words, creates a `Room` struct for each, and assigns those structs to the board array:

```c
void setuprooms(struct Room * board[3][3])
{
    char roomNames[9][20] = {
        "kitchen",
        "ballroom",
        "conservatory",
        "billiard room",
        "library",
        "study",
        "hall",
        "lounge",
        "dining room"
    };

    int counter = 0;
    struct Room * input;
    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {
            char* nname = roomNames[counter++];
            input = rmconstruct(nname, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
            board[x][y] = input;
        }
    }

    // this prints out the contents of my array just fine
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%s\n", board[i][j]->name);
        }
    }
```

And here is my `main` function:

```c
int main()
{
    struct Room * board[3][3];
    setuprooms(board);

    // this prints out garbage values for some reason?
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            printf("%s\n", board[i][j]->name);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's bad practice to cast the return value of `malloc`.  Just do `newRoom = malloc(sizeof(struct Room));`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `roomNames` is a variable local to `setuprooms` and thus it exhausts its lifetime once the function ends.  What this means is that the contents of that memory should be considered indeterminate at that point.

That's why your first print loop (i.e., inside `setuprooms`) works just fine.  However, once the function returns, your program now has permission to do whatever it wants with the memory.

To solve this, you have a few options:

1. Make `roomNames` into a global variable.
2. Declare `roomNames` to be a static variable (i.e., `static char roomNames[9][20] = ...`).  This keeps the program from deallocating that memory when the function ends.
3. Copy the strings using `strdup` from string.h.

Comment: wouldn't this also work `char *roomNames[9] = { "kitchen", ... }`?

Comment: Yeah, that would work since those strings would be string literals and thus remain in memory.

Comment: Although, in that case, you should attach the `const` qualifier to the array.  Also, the `name` field of `struct Room` should be changed to a `const char*`.